# How could I navigate between components using URLs in React Native using Expo?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Currently I'm using navigate method (from navigation) to go to my screens, e.g, *navigation.navigate("ArticleStackSearch")*, however I need to share posts/articles between users, something like https://myurl.com/a/123 (where *a* could be a fixed value and *123* the article ID.

I'm trying to use a "linkingConfig" which has this content:

```
const linkingConfig = {
  prefixes: ["myurl://", "https://myurl.com"],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Home: {
        screens: {
          ArticleStackDetails: {
            path: "a/:id",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And I'm passing through NavigationContainer like:

```
<NavigationContainer
    linking={linkingConfig}
    theme={MyTheme}
    fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}
  >
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Inicio" component={ArticleNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Sobre mi" component={AboutMe} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

ArticleNavigator Component:

```
   <ArticleStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <ArticleStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <ArticleStack.Screen
        name="ArticleStackDetails"
        component={ArticleDetailScreen}
      />

      <ArticleStack.Screen
        name="ArticleStackSearch"
        component={ArticleSearch}
      />
    </ArticleStack.Navigator>
```

I'm using the next command to open the app using URL but it seems this only works when the APK is installed:
`npx uri-scheme open myurl:// --android`

1. How could I open the app using an URL?
2. How could I navigate from ArticleDetailScreen to Home using local URL like "/Home" instead of navigation.goBack()?

Comment: What do you mean with 'but it seems this only works when the APK is installed'? Your approach is correct. When a user click on a deep link, if it has the app installed it will open the app, if it doesn't it will open the browser

Comment: I think my issues have been resolved with: https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/install/#android-install.
In the end, I did well with expo, but the react-native-share was not linked and react-native couldn't do it automatically,  I had to include cl.json.RNSharePackage in MainApplication.java.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely normal that it's only work if the user has the app installed. The scheme will not exist on the device of the user if the app is not installed.

What you can do:

- Dynamics Links with firebase. Very easy to implement, you can create dynamic link dynamically in your app and share the urls. You can then configure the project to redirect the user on the stores or website if they don't have the app installed or if the url has been opened on desktop. You should be aware though that the service will be discontinued in August 2025.
- Universal Linking on your website and redirect to the store if the user doesn't have the application installed. See the docs :
  https://docs.expo.dev/guides/deep-linking/
- Apparently, Expo has been working on that subjects and Expo Router
  comes with Deep Linking. You may want to migrate towards Expo
  Router. I did not try that solution yet.